# Append list based on specific value assigned within list

Tags: python-3.x

I've created a random database of 100 soccer players, with randomly generated names, positions, and ability (1-5). I want to append the list so that it reviews the ability of each player and assigns a value (20-100) based on their ability. 1 ability = 20 value. 2=40, 3=60, 4=80, and 5=100. In excel, for example, I would do a vlookup to the ability (1-5) and apply the value based upon the ability number. How would I go about doing this in a Python list? Thanks

```
from tabulate import tabulate

table = [['Dominik David', 'Defender', '3'],
['Reyansh Jake', 'Defender', '4'],
['Trey Bryant', 'Defender', '5'],
['Sylas Alfredo', 'Attacker', '1'],
['Robin Jeffery', 'Defender', '5'],
['Alfred Conor', 'Defender', '4'],
['Johnny Landyn', 'Defender', '1'],
['Kason James', 'Midfielder', '5'],
['Arjun Cohen', 'Goalkeeper', '4'],
['Joziah Ashton', 'Attacker', '2'],
['Rudy Hector', 'Attacker', '4'],
['Alexzander Lance', 'Goalkeeper', '5'],
['Colten Ashton', 'Goalkeeper', '1'],
['Cairo Marshall', 'Midfielder', '5'],
['Abraham Alvin', 'Attacker', '1'],
['Ezequiel Noe', 'Goalkeeper', '3'],
['Corey Jaxson', 'Attacker', '4'],
['Brixton Asa', 'Attacker', '2'],
['Kayson Pablo', 'Midfielder', '3'],
['Victor Neil', 'Goalkeeper', '4'],
['Jeffrey Azrael', 'Midfielder', '2'],
['Kaiser Lennon', 'Defender', '1'],
['Aaron Travis', 'Attacker', '4'],
['Terry Thiago', 'Attacker', '1'],
['Zaid Emilio', 'Attacker', '3'],
['Kobe Colson', 'Midfielder', '2'],
['Zayden Zeke', 'Goalkeeper', '1'],
['Ricky Colson', 'Defender', '2'],
['Noe Jermaine', 'Midfielder', '4'],
['Yusuf Chandler', 'Midfielder', '5'],
['Jackson Alexis', 'Defender', '5'],
['Drake Khalid', 'Attacker', '3'],
['Nova Julian', 'Defender', '1'],
['Zahir Emory', 'Defender', '4'],
['Mohamed Boston', 'Goalkeeper', '4'],
['Archer Memphis', 'Attacker', '1'],
['Castiel Julius', 'Goalkeeper', '4'],
['Miles Orion', 'Midfielder', '1'],
['Trey Eli', 'Defender', '3'],
['Trevor Elliott', 'Midfielder', '4'],
['Joaquin Ronin', 'Attacker', '3'],
['Keegan Vihaan', 'Attacker', '1'],
['Dalton Landen', 'Midfielder', '2'],
['Royal Westley', 'Attacker', '1'],
['Carl Elliot', 'Attacker', '2'],
['Tristen Peter', 'Goalkeeper', '5'],
['Abel Brett', 'Defender', '4'],
['Gael Zaiden', 'Midfielder', '2'],
['Gavin Dilan', 'Midfielder', '3'],
['Ray Armando', 'Goalkeeper', '5'],
['Paxton Jase', 'Defender', '5'],
['Zeke Eliel', 'Defender', '5'],
['Beau Will', 'Goalkeeper', '5'],
['Axl Leon', 'Goalkeeper', '3'],
['Abdiel Cohen', 'Defender', '3'],
['Thiago Jonah', 'Goalkeeper', '5'],
['Tadeo Ashton', 'Attacker', '5'],
['Niko Brayden', 'Defender', '3'],
['Royce Collin', 'Defender', '3'],
['Colson Ian', 'Attacker', '4'],
['Atreus Johnathan', 'Midfielder', '5'],
['Cash Maison', 'Goalkeeper', '2'],
['Conner Cesar', 'Defender', '5'],
['Emanuel Billy', 'Goalkeeper', '2'],
['Westley Alfred', 'Midfielder', '3'],
['Elliott Andrew', 'Defender', '2'],
['Ronin Hudson', 'Midfielder', '2'],
['Joe Henry', 'Goalkeeper', '3'],
['Ryker Cason', 'Goalkeeper', '3'],
['Idris Brecken', 'Defender', '1'],
['Stephen Archie', 'Defender', '2'],
['Howard Brecken', 'Defender', '3'],
['Genesis Ira', 'Defender', '5'],
['Genesis Leonardo', 'Attacker', '3'],
['Dominic Layne', 'Goalkeeper', '5'],
['Layton Alistair', 'Defender', '3'],
['Dante Quentin', 'Defender', '4'],
['Jayce Kyler', 'Goalkeeper', '5'],
['Theo Pablo', 'Goalkeeper', '2'],
['Reed Brett', 'Goalkeeper', '3'],
['Kamari Atreus', 'Midfielder', '1'],
['Mack Anthony', 'Defender', '1'],
['Mauricio Oscar', 'Midfielder', '2'],
['Ruben Malachi', 'Goalkeeper', '1'],
['Zavier Raylan', 'Goalkeeper', '4'],
['Colten Moises', 'Attacker', '1'],
['Kairo Brooks', 'Midfielder', '3'],
['Theo Chance', 'Attacker', '1'],
['Rocky Isaias', 'Midfielder', '4'],
['Matias Maurice', 'Goalkeeper', '3'],
['Patrick Layne', 'Midfielder', '1'],
['Kaison Lawson', 'Defender', '4'],
['Aryan Bryson', 'Attacker', '5'],
['Quinton Beckham', 'Goalkeeper', '2'],
['Gabriel Charles', 'Defender', '2'],
['Edison Bear', 'Defender', '1'],
['Jasper Demetrius', 'Attacker', '4'],
['Miles Jimmy', 'Attacker', '1'],
['Mathew Finn', 'Attacker', '3'],
['Stefan Corbin', 'Attacker', '4'],]

print(tabulate(table, headers=["ID", "Player Name", "Position", "Ability"], showindex="always"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below solution (Below lines to be addes before print statement):

```
# Create list of ability score
ability=[20,40,60,80,100]
for elements in table:
    #check last element of list convert it to int, -1 will make it 1-1 to 0 
    # which will be passed as index to ability list
    elements.append(ability[int(elements[2])-1])
```

or Using List comprehension as below:

```
ability=[20,40,60,80,100]
table=[elements+[ability[int(elements[2])-1]] for elements in table]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [list-comprehension.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> table = [['Dominik David', 'Defender', '3'], ['Reyansh Jake', 'Defender', '4'], ['Trey Bryant', 'Defender', '5'], ['Sylas Alfredo', 'Attacker', '1'], ['Robin Jeffery', 'Defender', '5']]
>>> value = {'1':20, '2':40, '3':60, '4':80, '5':100}
>>> new_table = [x+[value.get(x[-1])] for x in table]
>>> new_table
[['Dominik David', 'Defender', '3', 60], ['Reyansh Jake', 'Defender', '4', 80], ['Trey Bryant', 'Defender', '5', 100], ['Sylas Alfredo', 'Attacker', '1', 20], ['Robin Jeffery', 'Defender', '5', 100]]
>>>
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the end of your code should help you get what you want.

```
def check_num(number):
    if number == 1:
        res = 20
    elif number == 2:
        res = 40
    elif number == 3:
        res = 60
    elif number == 4:
        res = 80
    else:
        res = 100
    return res

for i in range(len(table)):
    table[i].append(check_num(int(table[i][2])))

print(tabulate(table, headers=["ID", "Player Name", "Position", "Ability","ability_value"], showindex="always"))
```